# How to sort list of tweets from Tweepy by date

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I am currently incorporating a sidebar into my website that will list tweets from various members of my team in order of most recent. I concatenated together the past 10 tweets from 2 random twitter users but can not figure out a good method to sort them. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the code I have thus far.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, acess_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

context = dict()
context['tweets'] = api.user_timeline(screen_name='tweetsauce', count=10, include_rts=False) + api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'neiltyson', count=10, include_rts=False)
```